# Programmatically determining if layer supports query capability via ArcGIS Server REST API?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3, arcgis-rest-api, layer-resource

I am using ArcGIS Server 9.3.1 SP 1. I want to be able to determine the capabilities of each published layer, specifically I am looking for all layers with query capabilities.

Being familiar with ArcGIS Server 10 I thought I could programmatically inspect the capabilities list on the layer response page. For example, [Average US Household Size](http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/USA_Average_Household_Size/MapServer/1?f=json&pretty=true) has MAP, QUERY, and DATA capabilities.

However it appears that ArcGIS Server 9.3.1 does not publish layer capabilities through the REST API. I think that I could get this information by scraping the HTML for the layer resource and looking for the list of supported operations in the HTML.

```
<a href="/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/USA_Average_Household_Size/MapServer/1/query">Query</a>
```

But this seems like brittle code.

How would you programmatically determine if a layer supports the query capability via the ArcGIS Server 9.3.1 REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way to programmatically determine if an ArcGIS Server 9.3.1 Layer has query capabilities is to make a `GET` request for the layer's resource page and search for "Query Layer" HTML content.

Here is a bit of Flex code that does just that. I specifically first search for "Support Operations" text and it's location in the content. If that is found I then search for "Query Layer" but **only** if it appears after where "Support Operations" was found to reduce chances of false positives. It's not ideal but it works in a pinch.

Error handling has been removed to simplify the example.

```
var layerResourcePage:HTTPService = new HTTPService(); 
layerResourcePage.url = layerUrl;
layerResourcePage.method = "GET";
layerResourcePage.resultFormat = HTTPService.RESULT_FORMAT_TEXT;

var asyncToken:AsyncToken = layerResourcePage.send();
var asyncResponder:IResponder = new AsyncResponder(onLayerResourcePageLoaded, onLayerResourcePageFailed, token);
asyncToken.addResponder(asyncResponder);

function onLayerResourcePageLoaded(result:ResultEvent, token:Object):void
{
    var html:String = result.result as String;

    var supportedOperationsIndex:int = html.indexOf("<b>Supported Operations: </b>");
    var supportedOpsFound:Boolean = supportedOperationsIndex != -1; 
    if (supportedOpsFound == true)
    {
        var queryCapabilityIndex:int = html.indexOf("Query Layer", supportedOperationsIndex);
        _queryCapabilityFound:Boolean = queryCapabilityIndex != -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article that shows how to get all the service layer's information:

[How to Get ArcGIS Server Layer Information](http://www.it-archives.com/Articles_GIS/GetArcGISServerLayerInformation.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, the REST API at 9.3.1 does not expose the layer's capabilities on in JSON response as far as I can tell.

Comment: You're right, this will work only with the 10 API, the 10 API will return the parameter: '"capabilities" : "Map,Query,Data"'